# Class not found laravel but exists

Tags: php, laravel, class, undefined

I'm trying to render PWA directives, but I have this error

> Error Class 'App\Services\PWA\MetaService' not found

I have this in `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('PWA', function (){
        return (new App\Services\PWA\MetaService())->render();
    });
 }
```

But the class exists
this is the class

```
<?php


namespace App\Services;


class MetaService
{
    public function render(): string
    {
        return "<?php \$config = (new \App\Services\PWA\ManifestService)->generate(); echo \$__env->make( 'pwa::meta' , ['config' => \$config])->render(); ?>";
    }
}
```

and that is located on app/Services/PWA

and I have the same problem with `ManifestService` (undefined class)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MetaService` class namespace must be `App\Services\PWA`. The path you are pointing to is just a folder structure, `namespace` is the thing that is important.